# Angular string variable not bound to template

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app containing an HttpInterceptor and an ErrorHandler. Errors intercepted by the HttpInterceptor are then handled by the ErrorHandler. The ErrorHandler pushes error messages onto a Subject, to which AppComponent is subscribed.

In this way I am hoping to display HTTP errors in the view of AppComponent.

The general approach seems to work, because I receive error messages in AppComponent when I call https://example.com/404 (= 404 error). However, the error message is not shown in the view.

HttpInterceptor:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class GlobalHttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        console.log("Error in GlobalHttpInterceptorService");
        return throwError(err);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

ErrorHandler:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  public subject = new Subject<string>();

  handleError(error: any) {
    console.log('Error in GlobalErrorHandlerService');
    this.subject.next(error.message)
  }
}
```

AppComponent (with template):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 'The error: {{ errorMessage }}',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';
  errorMessage: string = 'none';

  constructor(
    private service: Service,
    private errorHandlerService: GlobalErrorHandlerService
  ) {
    this.errorHandlerService.subject.subscribe((message) => {
      console.log('Error in AppComponent: ' + message);
      this.errorMessage = message;
    });

    // Call non existent URL = 404 error
    this.service.getNonExistentUrl().subscribe(() => console.log('bla'));
  }
}
```

Running the above I see this in the browser console:

[image]

Actually the GET call fails because of browser policies, which is fine. Any error will do to demonstrate the real problem:

In AppComponent I can `console.log()` the error message, but the message isn't bound to the view. `errorMessage` is still `"none"`:

[image]

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zikova?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handleError()` is called outside of the Angular Zone so the change detection will not detect any changes inside the component. You can use the  `run()` method from `NgZone` to avoid the problem.

Inject the `NgZone` into the `GlobalErrorHandlerService` and call the `next()` inside the `run` method.

```js
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

handleError(error: any) {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.subject.next(error.message);
  });
}
```

Another option would be to use `OnPush` change detection in your `AppComponent`. Set the `changeDetection` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`  and inject the `ChangeDetectorRef`. Inside the subscriber call the `detectChanges()` method to detect the changes.

```js
constructor(
  private service: Service,
  private errorHandlerService: GlobalErrorHandlerService,
  private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {
  this.errorHandlerService.subject.subscribe((message) => {
    console.log('Error in AppComponent: ' + message);
    this.errorMessage = message;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  });

  this.service.getNonExistentUrl().subscribe(() => console.log('bla'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I hadn't heard of Angular zones yet. I chose the first approach and it works.